# Выход за пределы localhost в чате python

Tags: python, localhost, чат

есть несложный чат.
Серверная часть:

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind (('127.0.0.1', 5000))
client = [] # Массив где храним адреса клиентов
print ('Start Server')
while 1 :
        data , addres = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print (addres[0], addres[1])
        if  addres not in client : 
                client.append(addres)# Если такого клиента нету , то добавить
        for clients in client :
                if clients == addres : 
                    continue # Не отправлять данные клиенту, который их прислал
                sock.sendto(data,clients)
```

Клиент:

```
import socket
import threading
def read_sok():
     while 1 :
         data = sor.recv(1024)
         print(data.decode('utf-8'))
server = '127.0.0.1', 5000  # Данные сервера
alias = input() # Вводим наш псевдоним
sor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sor.bind(('', 0)) # Задаем сокет как клиент
sor.sendto((alias+' Connect to server').encode('utf-8'), server)# Уведомляем сервер о подключении
potok = threading.Thread(target= read_sok)
potok.start()
while 1 :
    mensahe = input()
    sor.sendto(('['+alias+']'+mensahe).encode('utf-8'), server)
```

В пределах одного компьютера он работает отлично. Но подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы он работал не только в пределах localhost? Чтобы я к примеру мог мог общаться с другим компьютером. Что вписать в sock.bind ?

Comment: айпи и порт другого компьютера (если айпи там открытый)

Answer (score 2):

`(('0.0.0.0', 5000))` для сервера.

`server = '192.168.Х.У', 5000`   для клиента